# Implementing Java Web Service with xfc

Tags: java, web, service, xjc

I'm a newbie developing Web Services.
I've  created java classes from XSD using xjc command (command line "xjc ....\MySchema.xsd").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e. -->
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://SAS.Servicios/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <s:element name="S014">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="MensEntrada">
                    <s:complexType mixed="true">
                        <s:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <s:any processContents="lax"/>
                        </s:choice>
                    </s:complexType>
                </s:element>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="S014Response">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="MensSalida">
                    <s:complexType mixed="true">
                        <s:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <s:any processContents="lax"/>
                        </s:choice>
                    </s:complexType>
                </s:element>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
</s:schema>
```

xsd app generates some classes,

S014.java

```
...
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "mensEntrada"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "S014")
public class S014 {

    @XmlElement(name = "MensEntrada", required = true)
    protected S014 .MensEntrada mensEntrada;

    public S014 .MensEntrada getMensEntrada() {
        return mensEntrada;
    }

    public void setMensEntrada(S014 .MensEntrada value) {
        this.mensEntrada = value;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "content"
    })
    public static class MensEntrada {
        @XmlMixed
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        protected List<Object> content;
        public List<Object> getContent() {
            if (content == null) {
                content = new ArrayList<Object>();
            }
            return this.content;
        }
    }
}
```

S014Response.java

```
...
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "mensSalida"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "S014Response")
public class S014Response {

    @XmlElement(name = "MensSalida", required = true)
    protected S014Response.MensSalida mensSalida;

    public S014Response.MensSalida getMensSalida() {
        return mensSalida;
    }

    public void setMensSalida(S014Response.MensSalida value) {
        this.mensSalida = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "content"
    })
    public static class MensSalida {
        @XmlMixed
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        protected List<Object> content;
        public List<Object> getContent() {
            if (content == null) {
                content = new ArrayList<Object>();
            }
            return this.content;
        }
    }
}
```

ObjectFactory.java

```
...
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public S014Response createS014Response() {
        return new S014Response();
    }

    public S014 createS014() {
        return new S014();
    }

    public S014Response.MensSalida createS014ResponseMensSalida() {
        return new S014Response.MensSalida();
    }

    public S014 .MensEntrada createS014MensEntrada() {
        return new S014 .MensEntrada();
    }
}
```

I need to create a Web Service to read an incoming message "MensEntrada" and returns "MensSalida".

I was trying this:

```
...
@WebService (serviceName = "S014Service", portName="S014ServiceSoap", targetNamespace = "http://SAS.Servicios/")
public class S014Service extends AcceptMessage {

    public S014Service(WebServiceReceiver webServiceReceiver) {
        super(webServiceReceiver);
    }

    @WebMethod(action = "S014")
    public S014Response S014(@WebParam(name = "MensEntrada") S014 param) {
        String response = param.getMensEntrada().toString();
        response = response + "!!!";
        S014Response ms = new S014Response();
        return ms;
    }    
 }
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I read MensEntrada? How can I write MensSalida?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use the ObjectFactory to create your objects, as soon as you have them, use their setter methods to add your data, like MensSalida. Just read through your ObjectFactory and it will become clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your response. Should I to extends S014 with ObjectFactory? The problem is that I need to extend of AcceptMessage. Or Should create a new Object? For example ObjectFactory ob = new ObjectFactory();

Comment: Why don't you call param.getMensEntrada() inside S014Service#S014(S014) ? Then manipulate it as neccessary and then use ms = new ObjectFactory().createS014ResponseMensSalida() to get a new S014Response object. Then use the S014Response#setMensSalida(S014Response.MensSalida) of that class to set it to whatever value you like. Then just return ms.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got to read MensEntrada "Sometimes".
If I use this WebMethod ("S0142"):

```
@WebMethod(action = "S0142")
public void S0142(@WebParam(name = "param_name") S014 param)
{
    List<Object> ls = param.getMensEntrada().getContent();      
    Node ds = (Node)ls.get(0);
    String response = this.webServiceReceiver.processData(nodeToString(ds));
    List<Object> ls2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Node node = stringToNode(response);
    ls2.add(node);
    S014Response res = new S014Response();
    MensSalida ms = new MensSalida();
    ms.setContent(ls2);
    res.setMensSalida(ms);
    String test = nodeToString((Node)res.mensSalida.getContent().get(0));
}
```

It works, and I can set S014Response (thanks to Gil R.)

But If I use another this WebMethod ("S014"):

```
@WebMethod(action = "S014")
public S014Response S014(@WebParam(name = "MensEntrada") S014 param)
{
    List<Object> ls = param.getMensEntrada().getContent();      
    Node ds = (Node)ls.get(0);
    String response = this.webServiceReceiver.processData(nodeToString(ds));
    List<Object> ls2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Node node = stringToNode(response);
    ls2.add(node);
    S014Response res = new S014Response();
    MensSalida ms = new MensSalida();
    ms.setContent(ls2);
    res.setMensSalida(ms);
    String test = nodeToString((Node)res.mensSalida.getContent().get(0));
    return res;
}
```

It doesn't work, because param.getMensEntrada().getContent(); is not readable.

SOAP Envelope for "S0142" is this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sas="http://SAS.Servicios/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sas:S0142>
         <param_name>
            <sas:MensEntrada>
                [MyIncomingMessage]
            </sas:MensEntrada>
         </param_name>
      </sas:S0142>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Envelope for "S014" is this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sas="http://SAS.Servicios/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sas:S014>
          [MyIncomingMessage]
      </sas:S014>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

"...<param_name><sas:MensEntrada>...." is not present.
```

Is this correct to return MyOutgoingMessage?

```
@WebMethod(action = "S014")
public S014Response S014(@WebParam(name = "MensEntrada") S014 param)
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Can somebody help me with this?
Pls